# How to export columns as separate txt files from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, extract, directory-structure

It`s probably very simple, but I am also very new to R.

I have a dataframe structured like this (View(df)):

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsAWK.png)

What I would like to do is to save each LIST (column) into a seperate txt file. So the output should be something like this:

LIST1.txt:
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
text7
text8
text9
text10
(seperated by /n)

As many separate files as columns I had in the dataframe into a folder.

If I use write.table it prints out the whole dataframe into one big file, so probably I would need to use some kind of a loop to save each column. Can anyone help with this?

I have 'dplyr', 'readxl', 'tidyr', 'data.table' available to use.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `lapply` to loop over the column names, extract the column and save as `.txt` from the looped name in `base R`

```
lapply(names(df1), function(nm) write.table(df1[nm], paste0(nm, ".txt")))
```

Comment: ```plyr::l_ply(names(df1), function(nm) write.table(df1[[nm]], paste(nm, ".txt"))```

Comment: And I get this: :(

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

etc...

Comment: @Katalin I assume that you have a data.frame

Comment: Yes, the data is there, I checked it with View(data.frame)

Comment: @Katalin Can you show the `class(yourdata)`